# perl sending email works on one system but not another

Tags: perl

I have a simple sending email perl code.

```
 use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Time::Format;
    use Email::MIME;
    use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
    use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP;
    my $message = Email::MIME->create(
        header_str => [
            From    => 'me@provider.com',
            To      => 'me@provider.com',
            Subject => 'test',
        ],
        attributes => {
            encoding => 'quoted-printable',
            charset  => 'ISO-8859-1',
        },
        body_str => 'stefy test',
    );
    my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({
        host => 'my.server.smtp',
        port => 25,
    });
    sendmail($message, { transport => $transport });
```

I can it run with success in one system but not another.

1. Windows 7 professional -> success
2. Window Server 2008 -> failure

this is the exception I get:

```
unable to establish SMTP connection to my.server.smtp port 25

    Trace begun at D:\strawberryperl\perl\site\lib\Email\Sender\Transport\SMTP.pm line 193   Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::_throw('Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP=HASH(0x38
    0fef8)', 'unable to establish SMTP connection to my.server.smtp port 25') called at D:\strawberryperl\perl\site\lib\Email\Sender\Transport\SMTP.pm line 143
```

Any idea ?

thank you

Comment: Does your Windows 8 Server (I think you mean Windows Server 2008) have some firewall restrictions enabled?

Comment: yes sorry Window Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Comment: I think the network security should be the same as my system. I know I can send email from that system (Windows 2008 Server) with the Task Scheduler action of Send Email.

Comment: I checked the perl version and the one on Windows Server 2008 is a little behind. I wonder if that would help. `*** Windows Server 2008 ***
c:\stefy>perl -v

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-t
hread


*** Windows 7 Professional ***
C:\SPoRTBuild>perl -v

This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 1 (v5.24.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-t
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)`

Comment: I have to echo @blhsing.  This has the feel of a firewall issue.  I am not familiar with sending email from the Task Scheduler, it would not surprise me to find out that it talks directly to Microsoft Outlook or some other central email host and not directly to the SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

update of the perl version fixed the problem.

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 2 (v5.26.2) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-t
hread